# Get cms block parameter in Bock Class

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms-block

How can i get this "cat" parameter from my cms page block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Altravista_Carousel::product/carousel.phtml" cat="3"}}
```

in my Block Class?

> Altravista\Carousel\Block\Product.php;

Comment: have you got the solution from my answer?

Comment: Have you add this `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Altravista_Carousel::product/carousel.phtml" cat="3"}}` code in CMS > Page OR CMS > Block?

Comment: in cms pages HOME

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in like this

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Altravista_Carousel::product/carousel.phtml" cat="3"}}
```

Now you can get the data by calling:

```
$myVar = $block->getData('cat');
```

**OR**

```
$myVar = $block->getMyCat();
```

**Note :** You should use $block.

Comment: it does not works for me

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: no errros but get no products

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: this works  $productCollection = $productBlock->getProductCollection(array(23)); this does not works $productCollection = $productBlock->getProductCollection(array($block->getData('cat')));

Comment: also echo 'my var'.$block->getData('cat'); does not print anything

Comment: In your Phtml file write this code "$block->getData('cat');" then it's work

Comment: echo 'my var'.$block->getData('cat'); does not print anything in my phtml file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78055/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-altravista).

Comment: i'm sorry now i cannot :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the parameter in your block class, you should use something like this.

```
{{block class="Altravista\Carousel\Block\Product" template="Altravista_Carousel::product/carousel.phtml" cat="3"}}
```

Where Altravista\Carousel\Block\Product extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.